# Voice to Text on iOS10?

Tags: ios, iphone, voice-recognition, ios10

I'm Deaf and curious if there is the possibility to point the iPhone toward a speaker and see its text on the screen?

Not sure if iOS10 comes with that Voice to Text functionality or if an external app is required for this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Is this a general iOS 10 usage question or is this meant to be a programming question? Stack overflow is just for programming questions. If the former, please post at http://apple.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: good question. it's the former, looking for an app. will use your link, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As developer's point of view  in ios 10 there is **speech.framework** which can use to convert voice to text

for reference you can refer [speech.framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which about programming.